# How to make it so the pointer == null test passes?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is my code

```
struct customer_account {
      char login[20];
      char password[20];
      int balance;
};
typdef struct customer_account Account;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      Account *allUsers;  
      allUsers = (Account *) calloc(3, sizeof(Account));
      *allUsers = (Account) {"Ann", "nna", 100);
      *(allUsers + 1) = (Account) {"Beth", "hteb", 200};
      *(allUsers + 2) = (Account) {"Carl", "lrac", 500};
      printf("%p\n", allUsers + 3);
      printf("%d\n", (allUsers + 3) == NULL);
}
```

When I run the program, here is the output i am getting(don't understand the significance of the pointer value, haven't really studied hex).

```
0x9d6908c
0
```

From my understanding, what I am doing is requesting enough memory to store 3 Account structs from the operating system(I free it later) and that the pointer allUsers can be used to store the address of the first Account struct I obtained from dynamic allocation, and I can access the rest via pointer arithmetic. My question is from my code here, shouldn't (allUsers + 3) be be evaluating to null because there are only 3 Account structs? Is there a way to make it so (allUsers + 3) evaluates to null? My test there is evaluating to 0, false.

Comment: `shouldn't (allUsers + 3) be be evaluating to null` - only if `allUsers` is -3. Joke aside: this is not how memory allocation works. Also, pointer arithmetic. Memory is not "created" or "destroyed" upon allocation and deallocation. it's simply reserved or not reserved for use by your program. pointers, as a first approximation, are just indices into a huge global byte array, called the memory.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, shouldn't that be -3*(sizeof(Account)) ?

Comment: @Leeor quite irrelevant, that. Depends on how you interpret pointer arithmetic (but since it's already a pointless and impossible situation, I didn't feel like discussing this further)

Comment: Can you guys explain the downvotes? I thought this was a good question with good code example.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant and that huge global byte array is the heap right? because that's where memory that can be dynamically allocated is.

Comment: Downvotes can mean "doesn't show any research effort" - what research efforts have you made?  The question (and your comments) show a lack of understanding of C memory layout which is usually covered early on in any reference material

Comment: Ok more research effort next time. Thank you

Comment: @committedandroider Either "the"/"a" heap, or whatever else your implementation has for dynamic memory management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allUsers + 3` means simply the forth `struct customer_account` over from the address allocated to `allUsers`. It cannot possibly be `NULL` under any circumstances. It is the same as

```
&allUsers[3]
```

Its content can be zeroed out, but the pointer itself is a positive offset from a valid pointer, and the standard requires it to be non-NULL, because it is one byte past the end of the dynamically allocated array.

To see what is going on, do this experiment:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 4 ; i++) {
    printf("%p\n", (void*)(allUsers + i));
}
```

This will print four numbers - the first is `allUsers`, the second is `allUsers` plus the size of one `struct customer_account`, the third is `allUsers` plus the size of two `struct customer_account`, and the last one is what your program prints. As you can see, these addresses are a result of simple calculations, and have nothing to do with the *content* of the actual array.

Comment: Why cast the pointer to void*? I know %p is the format specifier for a pointer.

Comment: @committedandroider Not for "a pointer". It's for `void*`. ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) - see "argument type" column)

Comment: @committedandroider `%p` is not simply a pointer, it's a pointer to `void` (see the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html)). Standard says that `char*` will have the same layout as `void*`, but pointers to anything else need to be cast to `void*` when you pass it to `%p`.

Comment: Note that "positive offset from a valid pointer" is only meaningful for an offset which is still within an allocated array (or one past the end of it) - anything else causes undefined behaviour, so `allusers + 4 == NULL` has a chance of comparing true

Answer (score 0):

allUsers is a pointer pointing to an address in memory.
allUsers + n is a pointer pointing to a higher address if n>0.

allUsers and all the other addresses knows nothing about how much memory you have allocated with malloc. You need to keep track of that yourself, either in a separate variable or by allocating extra space for an element with some special terminating value.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that. I think i should just keep an int variable holding the number of accounts i need.